# Perl regex to tag the entire term

Tags: perl

I am trying to tag terms using a list of annotations. What I am specifically trying to achieve is that if the Perl regex identifies a term from a sentence it should tag the term with tags.

For example:

```
This drug has adverse effect on Lymphocytes, Lymphnodes, Lymph and pre-lymphocytes.
```

My list has the word Lymph, I am trying the following script.

```
open IN, "clean_cells.txt" or die "import file absent";
@array=<IN>;
foreach $words(@array)  
{
    @cells=split/\t/,$words;
    $value=$cells[0];
    $replace=$cells[1];
    foreach my $fp (glob("$Directory/*.txt")) 
    {
        @id=split('/',$fp);
        $id[1]=~s/.txt//ig; 
        $Pub=$id[1];
        open FILE, "<",$fp or die "Can't open $fp: $!";
        open OUT, ">C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TM\\Files\\$Pub" or die "Check      output status";
        while(<FILE>)
        {
            chomp $_;
            $line=$_;
            s/\b[\w\-]*$value[\w\-]*\b/<$replace>$&<\\$replace>/gi;
            # $string[$i]=$line;
            # while(($string[$i]=~m/\Q$value\E/i)||                                      ($string[$i]=~m/\Q$value(\w+)\E/i)||($string[$i]=~m/\Q(\w+)$value\E/i))
            # # if ($string[$i] =~ m/\b\w*$value\w*\b/i)
            # {
                # $value=~s/$value/<$replace>$value<\$replace>/i;
            # }
            print OUT "$line\n";
        }
        last;

    }   
    last;
}
```

I am hoping the final sentence should look like this:

```
This drug has adverse effect on tag Lymphocytes tag, tag Lymphnodes tag, tag Lymph tag and tag pre-lymphocytes tag.
```

tag: represents $replace in the above script.

The program tags the base word lymoh and not the entire term Lymphocytes, pre-lymphocytes.

Comment: And so ? Is it working ? What do you expect ? Do you have errors ? Finally, what is the question ?

Comment: Edit it more, because I still can't see a question.

Comment: @sputnick : Sorry it is not doing anything

Comment: Have you checked the file paths ?

Comment: YES. It's working. I am sorry I checked the path correctly. I had a small error in the path. Thanks man. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Just a small thing, I would like to clear. The code print next line before '>' .

Comment: Got, it I chomped $replace. Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your words together. The tricky part with that is determining what characters can make up words. A simpler approach (but perhaps not as exact) is to determine what makes up the delimiters. For example, you can use `\S+` to match consecutive non-whitespace characters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    for (split /(\S+)/) {    # The parens make the split keep the delimiters
        $_ = "<tag>$_</tag>" if /lymph/i;
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
Lymphocytes, Lymphnodes, Lymph and pre-lymphocytes.
```

**Output:**

```
<tag>Lymphocytes,</tag> <tag>Lymphnodes,</tag> <tag>Lymph</tag> and <tag>pre-lymphocytes.</tag>
```

Note that this is a non-destructive method, because the parens in the split regex will capture and return all the parts of the string.

This simplistic code will preserve your whitespace, though as you can see, it will put commas and other such separator characters inside your tags. This can be fixed by using another character class, such as `[^\s,.!?]+` (not whitespace, comma, period, exclamation point or question mark).

If you replace `<DATA>` with `<>`, you can use this script with redirection and skip the code about opening input and output files.

```
perl script.pl input > output
```

I would personally prefer such functionality, rather than hard-coded file paths, and it is often the way *nix programs work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP needs, you keep only tagged strings, but OP still need non matched ones. re-read his expected output.

Comment: That is an incorrect statement. I keep everything.

Comment: OK, sorry, you have changed sample INPUT

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot split at a delimiter as there are words like Vitamin E which are both part of the list and the sentence, splitting would miss words like Vitamin E as Vitamin would be considered as one unit and E as the other unit.

Comment: @Pink Ok.. is your list of words very long?

Comment: @TLP : Yes its almost 35,000 words

Comment: Do you have overlapping words, which have different values? Such as: `car => Ford, carpet => Rug`. This will create some confusion, as carpet would become: `<Rug><Ford>carpet</Ford></Rug>`. And worse, if you have tags which coincide with words, e.g. `xxx => foobar, foo => yyy`. In the latter case, you'd need to exclude the tags when doing your search and replace.

Comment: I have taken care of above cases. Each term is unique

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this (script rewriten):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $pub = "SOMETHING I HAVE TO CHANGE FOR THE SCRIPT TO WORK";
my $fp = "clean_cells.txt";
my $of = "C:\\Users\\Hrishi\\Desktop\\TM\\Files\\$Pub";
my $replace = 'tag';
my $word = "Lymph";

open FILE, "<", $fp or die "Can't open $fp: $!";
open OUT,  ">", $of or die "Check output status";

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    s/\b[\w\-]*$word[\w\-]*\b/<$replace>$&<\\$replace>/gi;
    print OUT $_; print;
}
```

**EDIT**:

- `\b` means [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `$&` means *the full matched part of the last regex*
- `[\w\-]` is a class of characters : *alphanumerics* + `_`, and `-`
- the final `gi` modifiers means respectively *all occurences* and *case insensitive*

Comment: Nope doesn't help. I am using while loop to make sure that entire line gets scanned, I think using an 'if' would exit the loop just after one match in the sentence. I want the program to tag all possible matches in the sentence

Comment: See my edited post with the full script

Comment: I have provided my full code.

Comment: Sorry, the code didn't anything.

Comment: Have you modified the filepath and see the output of the script ? The script display the result on STDOUT (terminal)

Comment: It prints OUT but without changing $value.

Comment: I have modified the script to create your wanted file.

Comment: I know what's wrong, you lack the declaration of `$Pub` used in your path. `my $pub = "something"`